# Message queue that removes messages on consumption

Tags: stream, rabbitmq, pipeline, message-queue

I'm working on a real-time pipeline (you know that the term "real-time" is tricky, so don't worry about delays) and my first thought was to use Kafka with some Python consumers. However, **Kafka does not allow to remove messages** once they are consumed, thus I don't like it so much.

I'm looking for something that:

- It is a **publisher-consumer framework**, such that, **I can delete the message** as soon as it has been processed. I want to process each message only once.
- I can develop the **consumers using Python**.
- It works in a "Kafka style", i.e. it can **scale in a horizontal manner**, so it has a good performance.

Basically, what I want to build is a pipeline similar to this:

```
input stream -> queue 1 -> consumer 1.1 -> queue 2 -> consumer 2.1 -> queue 3 ...
                           consumer 1.2               ...
                           ...
                           consumer 1.N
```

Right now I'm taking a look at RabbitMQ. At least, it seems that I'll be able to clean the queues with it.

Do you guys know some good alternatives?

Comment: Removing tag since this is not a Kafka question. Voting to close since it is asking for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also worth pointing out that Kafka **does** support exactly once processing. If messages are deleted, then you have **at most once**, not **exactly** once. The only reasonable way to guarantee records can be retried and processed upon error, for example, is to _not delete them_.